# DB Design for a show tracker

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I'm designing a page which will allow me to track my TV shows. I got the DB models down, but there's one thing which I'm not sure of. I want it so that if a user has watched an episode, they can just mark the episode as watched, but I don't know if it should be a ForeignKey/ManyToMany or what due to the fact that some users can have the episode watched, others don't.. :\

Does anyone have any suggestions for this problem? I'm thinking of making a new model, called episodeWatched but it's not very efficient to duplicate a model just simply for this..

Comment: Well can one user watch many episodes? Can an episode be watched by many people? I'm not sure what exactly is being asked here

Comment: Yes, a user can watch many episodes, and an episode can be watched by many people.

Comment: Sounds like a many to many relationship.  I would create a model (call it something like UserEpisodeWatched, or whatever name you like), and have it hold the ID of the User and the ID of the Episode.  Shouldn't be too costly because you only have two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ManyToManyField, in the `User` model or your user profile model, add

```
episodes=models.ManyToManyField(Episode)
```

Add episodes when the user watches it with

```
user.episodes.add(episode)
```

Find all episodes a user has watched with

```
Episode.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Or do the reverse, i.e. add a `users` field to the `Episode` model based on what you want to do

The Django docs list a similar example with articles and publications - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Django docs also explain how to use another model to store extra fields about the relationship as well, you could use it, for example, to store the time when the user watched the episode.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships